# Mongo lookup through array of ids

Tags: mongodb

how to correct lookup collection `product` which has array of ids of `prices` and need execute query exactly from `prices` collection query. Need to show price record with lookup product record
so, I have prices record

```
{
"_id" : "813f02ff-882e-44f7-b2bc-2f067427daf6",
"unit_amount" : 333,
"currency" : "USD",
"interval" : "year",
"active" : true
}
```

and product

```
"_id" : "3c46f277-8953-4f96-baf1-bd871ee3301f",
"name" : "test",
"prices" : [ 
    "813f02ff-882e-44f7-b2bc-2f067427daf6", 
    "f5c76122-6132-4e4b-a26b-41bbd6325acc", 
    "3e4be68e-fbed-47f7-b871-92de72cb00df"
]
```

and my query, I thought it should be like that

```
db.getCollection('price').aggregate([
{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "product",
            "let": { "prid": "$_id" },
            "pipeline": [
                { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": ["$$prid", '$prices'] } } }
              ],
            "as": "product_tbl"
        }
    }    
])
```

faced with

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing",
    "code" : 40081,
    "codeName" : "Location40081"
}
```

but it's not works. How it shoul be look ?

Comment: working here https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4NjGCVqgH5

Comment: Some of the documents don't have `prices` property in product collection.

Comment: yeah, that's the most logical reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like some of the documents in your product collection are missing `prices`
key. You can try this:

```
db.prices.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "product",
      "let": {
        "prid": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$addFields": {
            "prices": {
              "$ifNull": [
                "$prices",
                []
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$in": [
                "$$prid",
                "$prices"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "product_tbl"
    }
  }
])
```

Here, we recompute the `prices` and set it to empty array, if it's missing, before the `$match`. Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RNkjevs7tRJ).